# Vue Router cancelling route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I click on a link in my Vue app, it returns to the initial route where it is coming from.
I do not seem to have found this error/bug anywhere and currently do not know what to do

```xml
<router-link to="/user/info" >
  Information
</router-link>

<router-link to="/user/loan" >
  Loans
</router-link>
        
<router-link to="/user/documents" >
  Documents
</router-link>
```

If I click on Loans, it goes back to Information, if I click Documents, it goes back to Information

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, it sounds like the issue might be with the routes you've setup and not with the links themselves.

I'd check them to see if the paths you define in the `VueRouter` match the ones used in your `router-link` elements. You can find more info about defining routes in the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes).

Comment: So i have a dumbed down version of the app i'm working on here

https://github.com/I-GiM/Vue-router-bug

The routes i defined are also there

Would you mind checking it please
Instructions to set up are in README

Comment: Looks like you have your path setup as `/user/:select` which means the `:select` part is a dynamic segment and will match almost anything after the /user/ part. You also aren't specifying `/user/loan` or `/user/documents` routes anywhere. You can find more info here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: Thank you Bryce

I have found the mistake i made

There is a link that goes back to the route that page was coming from
The problem was that i passed the @click method to the entire component so anything clicked returns to the route it was coming from.

Lol!